# How can I stop divs getting bigger in a CSS Grid layout while adding other content in div?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

My div is getting bigger when I add anything inside div. I want to maintain the div's width from changing and expanding. How can I prevent the div from getting bigger in the CSS grid layout?

I have just added a little paragraph and it's expanding but I want to prevent divs from expanding. And I also want to set div's width automatic according to screen size.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>GTU Students-Care</title>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="title.png">
<meta name="viewport" content="width= device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!--bootstrap--------------------------------------------->
<!--
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
-->
<!--------------------------------------------------------->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Assistant|Barlow|Dosis|Gothic+A1|Monoton|Open+Sans|Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
<style type="text/css">
    header {
            background-color: #cc66ff;
            color: white;
            padding: 35px;
    }
    #gtu-header-home {
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: lighter;
        font-size: 4em;
        font-family:'Barlow', sans-serif;
        text-shadow: -1px 0px blue, 0px 1px blue, 1px 0px blue, 0px -1px blue;
    }
    #gtu-header-detail {
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        font-size: 25px;
    }
    #footer-copyright {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-family: 'Barlow', sans-serif;
    }
    footer {
        background-color:#ff9966;
        padding: 25px;
    }
    ul.navbar {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        background-color: gray;
    }
    .navbar a{
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        color: white;
        padding: 16px;
        font-weight: lighter;
    }
    .navbar a:hover {
        background-color: white;
        color: gray;
    }
    .navbar li{
        font-size: 26px;
        font-family: 'Barlow', sans-serif;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    #innerlist-1, #innerlist-2 {
        display: none;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
        position: absolute;
        min-width: 4cm;
        box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px -5px gray;
    }
    .innerlist a{
        color: black;
        padding: 0px;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    .innerlist a:hover {
        background-color: #ccc;
    }
    #sem:hover #innerlist-1{
        display: block;
    }
    #branch:hover #innerlist-2 {
        display: block;
    }
    #latest-posts {
        font-weight: lighter;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 5px;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Assistant', sans-serif;
        border: 3px solid gray;
        display: block;
        width: 6cm;
        margin: auto;
        background-color: gray;
        color: white;
    }
    #site-about {
        text-align: justify;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 33.33%;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    #site-about h1 {
        text-align: center;
    }
    body {
        background-color: #ceeddf;
    }
    #container {
        min-height: 100px;
        display: grid;
        grid-gap: 15px;
        grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
        padding: 15px;
    }
    #container > div {
        background-color: white;
        border: 2px solid gray;
        height: 12cm;
    }
    #upload:after {
        content: "";
        display: table;
        clear: both;
    }
    #main {
        background-color: #ff9999;
    }
    #latest-post-title { 
        padding: 1cm;
     }

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1 id="gtu-header-home">GTU Students Care</h1>
        <p id="gtu-header-detail">Tutorials | Question papers | Solution</p>
    </header>
        <ul class="navbar">
            <li id="sem"><a href="#">Semester</a>
                <div id="innerlist-1" class="innerlist">
                    <a href="#">First</a>
                    <a href="#">Second</a>
                    <a href="#">Third</a>
                    <a href="#">Forth</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li id="branch"><a href="#">Branch</a>
                <div id="innerlist-2" class="innerlist">
                    <a href="#">Computer</a>
                    <a href="#">Electronics</a>
                    <a href="#">Civil</a>
                    <a href="#">Mechanical</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="main">
            <div id="latest-post-title">
            <h1 id="latest-posts">Latest Uploads</h1>
            </div>          
        <div id="upload">
        <div id="container">
            <div id="con-1" class="con">
                <p>Question paper</p>
            </div>
            <div id="con-2" class="con"></div>
            <div id="con-3" class="con"></div>
            <div id="con-4" class="con"></div>
            <div id="con-5" class="con"></div>
            <div id="con-6" class="con"></div>
            <div id="con-7" class="con"></div>
            <div id="con-8" class="con"></div>
            <div id="con-9" class="con"></div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <div id="site-about">
            <h1>About</h1>
            <p></p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p id="footer-copyright">Copyright@ GTU Students Care</p>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add fixed width columns to #container, right now they are auto, so their width is adjusted based on content

```
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr
```

this will set the width ratio 1:1:1:1

Answer (score -1):

You might try using 'overflow: hidden;', or if it's vertical scrolling you want:

overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: scroll; (or auto)

Comment: Still same problem after adding overflow hidden. Thanks though.

Comment: Ok so, you might also need to add a fixed width, and then a max width so it doesn't exceed the screen size on smaller screens. Like this:

width: 500px; max-width:100%;

Answer (score -1):

With the same problem, and several suggestions that did no help, this worked for me.

- { box-sizing: border-box; }

Comment: @francisco please don't make such substantive changes to answers that other users post. Post your own answer or ask the OP to modify their answers instead.

Comment: This is not relevant to the problem at hand--if this solved your issue then you most likely had other changes that occurred and just didn't notice them due to caching until after making this change.

Comment: @TylerH what substancive? I added the question code plus the css guy answer on a snippet to see results.